# Mysql, update where not in array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, prepared-statement

I am trying to update with 0 the rows that is not in the array I get from the xml.

```
$sus = array();
foreach( $xml->property as $node ) {
  $sus[] = $node->suid;
}
$A = "'".implode("','",$sus)."'";
 echo $A;
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tabla SET alta = 0
WHERE suid NOT IN ($A)");
$sth->execute($sus);
```

When I echo $A it prints it out correctly like this:
'60','62','65','73','74','79','83','90','112','124'
However it does not do the update,
whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by escaping your XML values to avoid SQL injection:

```
$escapedValues = str_repeat('?,', count($sus) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE tabla SET alta = 0 WHERE suid NOT IN ($escapedValues)"
$sth->execute($sus);
```

Comment: That worked thanks, did´t know escapes where needed on pdo updates.
There is a bug with the names in your query.
Here is the full code in case its useful for anybody:
$sus = array();
foreach( $xml->property as $node ) {
  $sus[] = $node->suid;
}
$escapedValues = str_repeat('?,', count($sus) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tabla SET alta = 0 
WHERE suid NOT IN ($escapedValues)");
$sth->execute($sus);

Comment: Great! Glad for you. Just edited my answer with the appropriate variable name :)